# Chrome extension popup not showing anymore

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a new Chrome extension and everything was fine. However, today I was coding a new func, then I saw that my extension icon was grayed. And when I click on the icon, the popup isn't shown. **One interesting point is that the extension is working. No error logs.**

I commented all the code I wrote, but had no effect. If I open the link directly on the Chrome, it open a new tab showing the popup normally. [chrome-extension://extensionId/popup.html]

My manifest looks ok and the popup.html/js too. I really don't know what happened. Any ideas? Thanks!

**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Say It",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "__MSG_appDescription__",
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon-16.png",
    "128": "images/icon-128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "scripts/chromereload.js",
      "scripts/background.js"
    ]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "background",
    "bookmarks",
    "clipboardRead",
    "clipboardWrite",
    "contentSettings",
    "cookies",
    "*://*.google.com/",
    "debugger",
    "history",
    "idle",
    "management",
    "notifications",
    "pageCapture",
    "topSites",
    "storage",
    "webNavigation",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "nativeMessaging"
  ],
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html",
    "chrome_style": true
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "scripts/contentscript.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": false
    }
  ],
  "omnibox": {
    "keyword": "OMNIBOX-KEYWORD"
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "images/icon-19.png",
      "38": "images/icon-38.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Say It",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "images/icon-48.png"
  ]
}
```

**Popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="mainController as ctrl">
    <h4>Choose your Destiny!</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" ng-click="ctrl.kappa()">Kappa</button>
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-secondary" ng-click="ctrl.pride()">Pride</button>
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-success" ng-click="ctrl.fon()">Fon</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Popup.js

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app').controller('mainController', function () {
    var self = this;

    //Por localStorage

    console.log(localStorage.getItem('kappa'));

    //Por API
    chrome.storage.local.get('value', function (res) {
      console.log(res);
    });

    this.kappa = function () {
      console.log('Seu Kappa!');
    };

    this.pride = function () {
      console.log('Seu KappaPride!');
    };

    this.fon = function () {
      console.log('Fon!');
    };
  });
})();
```

Comment: You're using a page_action, which is intended to be shown only on the URLs you specify. You probably need [browser_action popup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction). Also, to see the errors in the popup rightclick it and then `Inspect`.

Comment: I tried to Inspect the popup, but the windows didn't open. I will try using browser_action. I didn't know about the page_action, thanks for the explanation. I'll try now and update my answer afterwards.

Comment: Perfect! @wOxxOm Now everything is working again. Thank you for sharing your knowledge. Appreciated!

Comment: You appear to have specified way more `permissions` than you are probably using. While this is not a problem for an extension which you are going to use yourself, it is a bad practice. In addition, if you post the extension to the Chrome store, when users install it they will see warnings regarding many of the permissions.

Comment: @Makyen Thanks for the advice. I was testing somethings on my extension that need this permissions. However, I'll keep in mind this info when I post it on Chrome store.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

In `manifest.json` replace `"page_action"` (which only works on specific pages) with `"browser_action"` (which works on all of them).

Comment: Thank you and @wOxxOm fo the help. Now everything is right!

Comment: Works for me. Why is this so?

Comment: That is worked for me. Thanks. But, official document of Google was defined page_action. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Comment: @narupo use a `page_action` for an extension that only appears on certain pages, use `browser_action` to always appear. Both are valid.

Comment: late to the party, but I also used `browser_action` and it's still not working/showing popup. Anything I am missing?

Comment: @AdorableVB it's probably better to ask in your own question with examples of your code, it's really hard to figure out what you're missing from a comment.

Answer (score 5):

If changing it from "page_action" to "browser_action" still does not work, check to see if your manifest defined any background.js and if that background.js has set any rules.

**For example:**

In the case of the [Getting Started](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) example from Google, the background.js had an onPageChanged rule where the url host must be 'developer.chrome.com' for the extension to be active.

replace

```
chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function () {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
        conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { hostEquals: 'developer.chrome.com' },
        })
        ],
        actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
    }]);
});
```

with

```
new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()
```

so that the extension popup will be active for any page.

(This took me ages to figure out, so hope it'll help others)

Answer (score 0):

I was following along with [the tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/getstarted/) and had the exact same problem on Chrome 87. The issue is that the page doesn't have access to the extension. To solve this problem:

#### Click on the extension icon in the top right

It should be next to your user icon.

[image: An arrow pointed to the extension (puzzle piece) icon]

#### Under the "Access Requested" header, click on your extension's name

You may or may not have extensions under "Full access" (i.e. I have the react developer tools). This does not matter.

[image: AN arrow points to the extension name under the header]

Your extension should now show it's popup. Note that you will have to do this each time you reload the extension.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the Get Started(https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/getstarted/) page carefully, you see the background.js add rules for your page.

You can create an always-true PageStateMatcher to activate your page action.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {

    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
      chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
        conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
          // Comment below line so that PageStateMatcher match any pages
          // pageUrl: {hostEquals: 'developer.chrome.com'},
        })
        ],
        actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
      }]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone landing here from Google: the API has changed with manifest version 3.

Now, `page_action` and `browser_action` are merged under the property `action`. [Read more in the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/).