# Showing popup on page_action

Tags: google-chrome-extension

What am I missing that popup is not being shown?

In an extension folder I have four files. I load that folder as extension. I can see the icon, but when I click on it popup is not shown. Why?

1. `content_script.js`: empty (just added so that I can load the extension)
2. `icon.png`: It is shown, when I load extension.
3. `manifest.json`:

```js
{
    "name": "Popup poc",
    "version": "1.4",
    "description": "Simple popup example",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content_script.js"]
        }
    ],
    "page_action": {
        "default_name": "Display Map",
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

4. `popup.html`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Popup</title>
</head>

<body>
    This is body
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace "`page_action`" with "`browser_action`" in your `manifest.json`. You should be able to see the popup on all pages this way.

It's possible duplicate of: [Chrome extension popup not showing anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055526/chrome-extension-popup-not-showing-anymore?rq=1)
But it seems like I don't have enough reputation points to flag it for that.

---

### Popups only for certain hosts URL patterns

**(Edit)**

If you want your popup available only on certain sites (for example, only on Google), then you need to specify `declarativeContent` permissions in your manifest, and also a little setup in a background script.

So, your `manifest.json` would look something like this:

```js
    {
        "name": "Popup poc",
        "version": "1.4",
        "description": "Simple popup example",
        "permissions": ["declarativeContent"],
        "content_scripts": [
            {
                "matches": ["https://www.google.com/*"],
                "js": ["content_script.js"]
            }
        ],
        "background": {
          "scripts": ["background.js"],
          "persistent": false
        },
        "page_action": {
            "default_name": "Display Map",
            "default_icon": "icon.png",
            "default_popup": "popup.html"
        },
        "manifest_version": 2
    }
```

Your `background.js` would look like this:

```js
    chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
        chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
          chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
            conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
              pageUrl: {hostEquals: 'www.google.com'},
            })
            ],
                actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
          }]);
        });
      });
```

This code is largely from the [Getting Started Tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted).

Comment: But I need page action not browser action. I need to change the icon.

Comment: Thanks, How should I match all the URLs?

Comment: I got it, just removing "pageUrl: {hostEquals: 'www.google.com'}," OR all the rules, does the job. Thanks